# Cannot find my phone brand in the vendor ids

Tags: java, android, driver, android-virtual-device

I am connecting my Intex Aqua Y2 to my eclipse in Ubuntu 12 to run my android applications directly on the device. But it shows an invalid device when the avd manager runs. But as i see this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html i don't see the the vendor id for my phone.

How can i then install its driver. Can i use any alternate Vendor ID? I tried installing the pc suit of it of windows platform through wine, but this didnt help.

Could anyone how i proceed on this? Do i need to write my own kernel?

Comment: Add your VID to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini, create a udev rule as described in the developer docs to grant permission, and restart udev.  No "driver" is used for adb on linux - it is all handled by the adb program in userspace.

Comment: But my vendor name is not there in the list. What id can i use?

Comment: Names mean little.  Use the actual VID of the phone you are trying to connect.  `lsusb` should help you find it.  If you can't figure out which device is the phone, run it both without the phone connect and then with and look at the difference.